# How to calculate column y+1 based on value in prior column y more efficienty (Monte Carlo SImulation)

Tags: python, performance, kernel, montecarlo, cpu-speed

my current code is following:

```
stock_values = np.zeros([path, steps+1])
stock_values[:, 0] = s
for y in range(0, steps):
    stock_values[:, y+1] = stock_values[:, y] * (
        np.exp(change[:,y]))
```

with:

```
change = (r_d - 0.5*(sigma_d ** 2)) * deltat + sigma_d * np.sqrt(deltat) * np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(path, steps)) + np.random.poisson(lambda_j*deltat,size=(path, steps))* np.random.normal(r_j,sigma_j, size=(path, steps))
```

Stock_values and change are both an array with 1 000 000 x 1015 elements
So, I run a Monte Carlo Simulation with GBM and Jump Diffusion, 1 000 000  paths and 1045 steps. 
Like this, the computing time is pretty slow, esp. since I would rather like to use 100 000 000 paths for this. Unfortunately python only uses one kernel for the loop and lets the 7 others unused. For the "Change" matrix, it is able to use all kernels... (Sorry, do not have good technical/hardware skills and knowledge...)

I am looking for a function to exchange the "for" loop which calculates column y+1 based on value in col y, y+2 based on y+1 etc until y+1044.

Any ideas? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One first easy improvement if you have enough memory is to move `np.exp` out of the loop:

```
stock_values = np.zeros([path, steps+1])
stock_values[:, 0] = s
e = np.exp(changes)
for y in range(0, steps):
    stock_values[:, y+1] = stock_values[:, y] * e[:,y]
```